# Boto3 & moto - Route53 error creating dns record set, it can't find the hosted zone

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53, moto

I am having some troubles with Boto3 and the moto library for mocking AWS.

I am creating a hosted zone like this:

```
@moto.mock_route53
def create_dns_zone(route53_client, vpc, name='test.'):
    hosted_zone = route53_client.create_hosted_zone(
        Name=name,
        VPC={'VPCId': vpc.vpc_id},
        CallerReference=str(hash('test')),
        HostedZoneConfig=dict(
            PrivateZone=True,
            Comment="testing zone",
        )
    )
    return hosted_zone
```

The vpc object and the route53_client object are created in the same region. And I changed some properties of the vpc object like this:

```
ec2.modify_vpc_attribute(
    EnableDnsHostnames={'Value': True}, EnableDnsSupport={'Value': True}, VpcId=vpc.vpc_id
)
```

The `create_dns_zone` function returns this object:

[image: hosted zone]

And then I try to create the dns registry in AWS:

```
@moto.mock_route53
def create_dns(client_route53, zones, total_dns=1):
    # zones is the hosted zone object    
    hosted_zone_id = session.get_hosted_zone(Id=zones.get('HostedZone').get('Id'))

    changes_dns = []
    for index in range(total_dns):
        index += 1
        data_dns = dict(
            Action='CREATE',
            ResourceRecordSet=dict(
                Name='dns-test.{index}.testing.internal'.format(index=index),
                Type='A',
                TTL=30,
                ResourceRecords=[{'Value': '10.10.0.1{index}'.format(index)}]
            )
        )
        changes_dns.append(data_dns)

    return client_route53.change_resource_record_sets(
        HostedZoneId=hosted_zone_id,
        ChangeBatch=dict(
            Comment='testing dns',
            Changes=changes_dns
        )
    )
```

So when I want to create an entry in the route53 dns server names it throws this exception:

`Exception: An error occurred (404) when calling the GetHostedZone operation: Not Found`

And scrolling down in the error log:

`botocore.parsers.ResponseParserError: Unable to parse response (syntax error: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received:
b'Zone VINSTS51LDMLEAA not Found'`

And if I call the function `list_hosted_zones()` it returns an empty list.

Did I do something wrong? Or miss anything?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moto AWS mock implementation doesn't have 100% coverage. In this case, route53 only is [12% implemented](https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/e1b3b68b986726d01e368a94f2388936201ee337/IMPLEMENTATION_COVERAGE.md#route53---12-implemented).
I think this is your problem.